# Erro: collections.defaultdict' object has no attribute 'iteritems' Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, collection

Ao executar o código abaixo o compilador retorna a seguinte mensagem:

> ```
> collections.defaultdict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
> ```

Estou utilizando a versão 3.6.5 do Python.

Segue o código:

```
import collections 
salario_experiencia = [(83000,8.7), (88000,8.1),
                        (48000,0.7),(76000,6),
                        (69000,6.5),(76000, 7.5),
                        (60000,2.5), (83000,10),
                        (48000,1.9),(63000,4.2)]

def tenure_bucket(experiencia):
     if experiencia < 2:
        return "Menos que 2 anos"
    elif experiencia < 5:
        return "Entre dois e 5 anos"
    else:
        return "Mais que 5 anos"

salary_by_tenure_bucket = collections.defaultdict(list)

for salario, experiencia in salario_experiencia:
    bucket = tenure_bucket(experiencia)  
    salary_by_tenure_bucket[bucket].append(salario)
    #print (salary_by_tenure_bucket) 
media_salario = {
    tenure_bucket : sum(salario)/len(salario)
    for tenure_bucket, salarios in salary_by_tenure_bucket.iteritems()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

São dois problemas:

1. No [Python 3 não existe mais `iteritems()`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python3.0#Built-In_Changes), sendo substituído por [`items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items).
2. Ao fazer o cálculo:

   ```
   sum(salario)/len(salario)
   ```

Você está usando a variável `salario`, que foi usada algumas linhas acima para receber o valor do salário. Portanto, neste ponto do código esta variável contém um número. E ao chamar [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) e [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) com um número, [vai dar erro](https://ideone.com/pQsOWc).

O que você quer é usar a variável `salarios` (no plural), que você criou dentro da sua [*dict comprehension*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
media_salario = {
    tenure_bucket: sum(salarios) / len(salarios) # use "salarios" em vez de "salario"
    for tenure_bucket, salarios in salary_by_tenure_bucket.items() # use "items" em vez de "iteritems"
}
```

Repare que você faz `for tenure_bucket, salarios`, ou seja, a variável `salarios` (no plural) é que deve ser usada. A variável `salario` (no singular) foi usada no *loop* `for` anterior, mas não tem uso neste trecho.

Comment: Era exatamente isso.
Problema resolvido!

`media_salario = {
tenure_bucket : sum(salarios)/len(salarios)
for tenure_bucket, salarios in salary_by_tenure_bucket.items()}`
Output:
`{'Mais que 5 anos': 79166.66666666667, 'Menos que 2 anos': 48000.0, 'Entre dois e 5 anos': 61500.0}`